# MySQL - Using a CASE statement vs. lookup table?

Tags: mysql, join, case

I'm debating between using a `CASE` statement or a lookup table to replace text from `table2.columnB` when `table1.columnB = table2.columnA`. I'd rather use a lookup table because it's easier to manage.

Our database pulls all the customer order information from our online store. It receives all the state names in full and I need to replace all instances of U.S. states with their 2-character abbreviation. (e.g. Texas -> TX)

How would I use a lookup table with this query for `State`?

Here's my query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e44aa3/12/0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In general, a lookup table is more expensive in terms of execution time. If you have few rows it may not be noticeable, though.

Comment: Or possibly a function , at least you wouldn’t Have to repeat code.

Comment: @P.Salmon by placing a `CASE` expression in a function?

Comment: Why do you store the full name of the state in the table `order`? You should store the abbreviation and only when the full name is really needed you should look it up in `state_abbreviations`. The abbreviation should be the lookup key.

Comment: The state is received from our website in a customer order when they enter their address information.

Comment: For 50 different case you can't use a CASE expression. Use the lookup table. It may be a bit heavier but you can't have 50+ lines of code where you could have 1 or 2.

Comment: Given that the state names are received from the online store, how would I write the lookup in my query to `JOIN` with my `state_abbreviations` table?

Comment: ‘by placing a CASE expression in a function? ’ -yes itt’s unlikely there will more any time soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question how would add the lookup table in your code, you must add this join:

```
LEFT JOIN `state_abbreviations` AS `sa` ON `sa`.`shipping_zone` = `o`.`shipping_zone`
```

and change this line:

```
`o`.`shipping_zone` AS `State`
```

with:

```
COALESCE(`sa`.`zone_abbr`, `o`.`shipping_zone`) AS `State`
```

so you get the abbreviation returned.
See the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e44aa3/21).
Results:

```
Order ID  Name          State   Qty Option  Size    Product     Ref
12345     Mason Sklut   NC      1   R       L       Tee         R / Tee L
12346     John Doe      OH      2   Bl      S       Hood        2x Bl / Hood S
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` only returns when it finds a match, right? How would I get this to return all the matches and non-matches?

Comment: If there is no match what do you want returned? The full name?

Comment: Yes. The only reason I need this is in case it's for an international order because I don't have abbreviations for all the provinces outside the U.S.

Comment: See my edited answer with a LEFT join and COALESCE().

Comment: Is there a way to JOIN a lookup table for partial string matches?

Comment: I can't say without knowing about the data, so post a question with sample data and expected results and explain what you mean by partial string matches.

Comment: Follow up question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61196991/mysql-join-with-table-on-partial-string-match]

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CASE` expression is sure an option. However, it does not scale well: there are 50+ states in the US, so you would need to write 50 `when` branches, like:

```
case state
    when 'North Carolina' then 'NC'
    when 'Ohio' then 'OH'
    when ...
end
```

Creating a mapping table seems like a better idea. It is also a good way to enforce referential integrity (ie ensure that the names being used *really* are state names).

That would look like:

```
create table states (
    code varchar(2) not null primary key,
    name varchar(100) not null
);
```

In your original table, you want to have a column that stores the state code, with a foreign key constraint that references `states(code)` (you may also store the state name, but this looks like a less efficient option in terms of storage).

You can do the mapping in your queries with a `join`:

```
select t.*, s.name state_name
from mytable t
inner join states s on s.code = t.state_code
```

Comment: For the mapping statement, how would that be placed in my query since I have a few subqueries already?