# MySQL - JOIN with table on partial string match

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-like, lookup

Trying to `LEFT JOIN` a table with partial string match. I've tried changing the wildcard in the `LIKE` condition, but it still only searches for the full string. Any suggestions? I've got a list of product abbreviations stored in a table. Would be easier to manage this list with partial matching versus having to spell out every product.

Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TABLE `order`
(
  order_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  shipping_firstname VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  shipping_lastname VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL
  );

CREATE TABLE order_option
(
  order_id integer NOT NULL,
  order_product_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE order_product
(
  order_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  quantity INT (11) NOT NULL,
  order_product_id INT (11) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR (55) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE product_abbreviations
(
  product_name VARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
  product_abbr VARCHAR (55) NOT NULL
);

INSERT `order`
  (order_id, shipping_firstname, shipping_lastname)
VALUES
  (12345, 'Mason', 'Sklut'),
  (12346, 'John', 'Doe');

INSERT order_option
  (order_id, order_product_id, `value`)
VALUES
  (12345, 101, 'Large'),
  (12345, 101, 'Red'),
  (12346, 102, 'Small'),
  (12346, 102, 'Blue');

INSERT order_product
  (order_id, quantity, order_product_id, name)
VALUES
  (12345, 1, 101, 'T-shirt for Halloween'),
  (12345, 2, 101, 'T-shirt for Spring Break'),
  (12346, 5, 102, 'T-shirt for Pacific West');


INSERT product_abbreviations
  (product_name, product_abbr)
VALUES
  ('T-shirt for', 'Tee'),
  ('Halloween', 'Hallo'),
  ('Spring Break', 'SB'),
  ('Pacific West', 'PW');

LEFT JOIN `product_abbreviations` AS `pa` ON `pa`.`product_name` LIKE CONCAT('%',`op`.`name`,'%')
```

**See full query here:** 

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=536e2f367cebc053e95709ec7d90a7aa

**Expected Output:**

```
Order ID  | Name        | Qty | Option | Size | Product    | Ref
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345     | Mason Sklut | 1   | R      | L    | Tee Hallo  | R / Tee Hallo L
12345     | Mason Sklut | 2   | R      | L    | Tee SB     | 2x R / Tee SB L
12346     | John Doe    | 5   | Bl     | S    | Tee PW     | 5x Bl / Tee PW S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want the pattern matching the other way around. That is, the product name should contain the product abbreviation:

```
LEFT JOIN `product_abbreviations` AS `pa` 
    ON `op`.`name` LIKE CONCAT('%', `pa`.`product_name` ,'%')
```